# WatchOS emulator not starting using Xamarin, Visual Studio, and WatchCommunication Demo

Tags: xamarin, watchos-2, watchos-simulator

I downloaded the Watch Connectivity sample app (https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monotouch/watchOS/WatchConnectivity/) and ran it. The iPhone emulator comes up but the watch emulator does not. Has anybody set this up?

I'm using Xamarin and Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the sample and selected the `WatchConnect.Onwatch` as my start up project. In doing so, I was able to set my target simulator as `Apple Watch Series 2 - 42mm watchOS 3.1`. If you are missing the iWatch Simulators, simply download them in XCode by opening `Preferences -> Components`.

When I started my debugging session, both an iPhone and the iWatch Simulator booted up.

Although, when the debugging session began, I had to choose the application (i.e. "WatchConnectivity") on the iPhone Simulator myself for it to launch.

[image: WatchConnectivity Sample Project]

Comment: I was trying to do this from Visual Studio on a Surface Book connected to a MacBook Air. Were you using Xamarin Studio on a Mac?

Comment: I ran it on my Mac. Never got it resolved on my Windows machine.